# Why aren't other states objecting against Iowa and New Hampshire being the first primary states?

Tags: united-states, primaries

During both Republican and Democratic primaries, Iowa and New Hampshire get a disproportionate amount of attention due to being the first two states to run the vote. This gives these two small states a much larger degree of influence over the elections than places like California or Texas.

So why aren't other states demanding that they get a fair treatment during the primaries? Couldn't California pass a law that sets their primaries to January to make sure they're voting sooner than others?

Comment: Yes, they could do that. Clearly they don't think there is a good reason to do it, so the question has a problem with its premises (they don't care about IA and NH getting some extra media coverage).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes states try to do something like that (e.g. Florida and Michigan in [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries#Disputed_primaries)).  Then Iowa and New Hampshire move their caucus and primary before that date.  Iowa has more flexibility than a primary state in setting its date, as all it needs to hold the caucus is a recent voters list (because it doesn't need ballots to run a caucus).  New Hampshire is such a small state, that it can quickly disseminate ballots.  Larger states tend to be bound with more rules and can't adjust as quickly.  They have to announce their primary dates further in advance and can't keep changing them to stay ahead.

The next thing that happens is that the national committee can punish states for jumping in line.  Again in 2008, both the Democrats and [Republicans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries) took half the delegate representation from Florida and Michigan for jumping ahead.

Since 2008, states haven't bothered, because they know that they will be punished if they do and that Iowa and New Hampshire will move ahead of them anyway.  So there is no benefit from moving earlier.

Another issue is that while it may seem like Iowa and New Hampshire get disproportionate representation, other states can't really duplicate that.  Iowa and New Hampshire benefit not just from being early but being small.  They expect to have opportunities for people to meet the actual candidates.  That wouldn't have worked in Florida and Michigan even if they had been allowed to go first.  Those states are too big for such direct politics to be practical.

Moving the primaries earlier also creates problems with the Christmas holidays (which is why the parties prefer to have none until February).

A final issue is that if the election is heavily contested, it's actually the later states that have more influence.  This is because early states serve to eliminate lesser candidates.  But later states do more to actually choose among the real candidates, as the vote is spread over fewer possibilities.  This role is usually taken by the states in the middle of the primary season, but in a truly contested election, it would be the last states that really mattered.  They would choose the actual winner.

In 2008, Barack Obama won the pledged delegates by sixty-two over Hillary Clinton.  But John Edwards had sixty-five delegates.  If Edwards' delegates had chosen Clinton instead, she would have been ahead on pledged delegates.  The early states lost that portion of their vote.  If they had gone later, they would have had less of a role in eliminating Edwards but more of a role in choosing between Obama and Clinton.  Note that Obama did not win a majority of the delegates until the convention (when the unpledged delegates voted).

Comment: When push came to shove, the 2008 Democrats allowed all of Florida's and Michigan's delegates to fully participate and vote at the convention, [with full voting rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Florida_Democratic_primary#The_Democratic_National_Committee's_Rules_and_Bylaws_Committee).  Neither Clinton nor Obama wanted to be perceived as suppressing votes.